# How to bind property to a TreeView

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I want to create a relationship between my treeview and datagrid 
 I have a method called SelectedTestElement that calls a the SearchGrid method

ViewModel:

```
     public TestElementViewModel SelectedTestElement
    {
        set
        {
            if (_selectedTestElement == value) return;
            this._ selectedTestElement = value;


            SearchGrid(value.Id, new List< TestElementViewModel>( testElementViewModel.GetAllTreeNodes()));

        }
        get
        {
            return this._ selectedTestElement;
        }

    }
```

I want to bind this property in my xaml TreeView

```
   <TreeView Margin="644,137,6,6" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding MessageElements,  Mode=TwoWay}" TreeViewItem.Selected="{Binding SelectedTestElement, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Is treeView.Selected a best way to make the property call in treeview?

Edit:

ViewModel:

I select a treenode i.e SelectedTreeNode will be bind to TreeView.SelectedItem

```
      public TreeNodeViewModel SelectedTreeNode
     {
        set
        {
            if (_selectedTreeNode== value) return;
            this._selectedTreeNode = value;

            //search the treenode id
            SearchGrid(value.Id, TestFieldVModel.GetAllTestField());

        }
        get
        {
            return this._selectedTreeNode;
        }

    }
```

//do the search and highlight the matching id grid

```
       public void SearchGrid(int id, ObservableCollection<TestFieldViewModel> msgField)
     {
        foreach (var c in msgField)
        {
            c.DisplayColor = c.Id == id ? Brushes.DarkOrange : Brushes.Black;
            c.DisplayFont = c.Id == id ? FontWeights.Bold : FontWeights.Normal;

          // SearchGrid(id, c.GetAllTestField());
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
      <TreeView Margin="644,137,6,6" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeNodes,  Mode=TwoWay}" TreeView.SelectedItem ="{Binding Path= SelectedTreeNode, Mode=TwoWay}" >
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work, you're trying to bind an event to a property on your view model.

I would recommend that you use the `TreeView.SelectedItem` property and bind that to a new property on your view model that accepts a `TreeViewItem`.  Then either modify your `SelectedTestElement` property to look at the new selected item property and determine the appropriate `TestElementViewModel` to return, or you could have the `set` of the new selected item property set the `this._selectedTestElement' directly.

Comment: ..I updated my code based on your suggestion but looks like when i try to debug it wont get into that property.

Comment: @AydaSayed Do you have WPF binding debugging enabled, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409960.aspx.  I suspect that your property `SelectedTreeNode` needs to be of type `TreeViewItem` not your view model.  And you will need to have a second property which returns the view model based on the `TreeViewItem` that is selected.

Comment: Gorilla I figure out a way to select a node from the tree now I want to highlight a row in my grid if there is a matching id with the tree. Seems like the method  I have doesn't work. any suggestion?